# If I'm reborn as a Deva, how long will my lifespan be?

Tags: rebirth, samsara, deva

If I am reborn as a Deva, how long would my lifespan be before I'm forced back into Samsara? Factors?

Comment: If by any chance you think that living long is a blessing, imagine losing a limb at the age of 10 when your lifespan is an eon. Samsara is not a place for loitering be it in any form.

Comment: @Sampath Being reborn as a Deva is seen as a punishment?

Comment: Even if you are born as a Deva, you still are feeling the feelings like anger, sadness, jealousy, etc.  Being re-born altogether is not viewed as a blessing in Buddhism. Because you have little or no control over where you are born. AFAIK its not referred as a punishment either, but its not a thing that is desired. Main goal of a Buddhist is to break the Death-Rebirth cycle -> Nirvana.

Answer (score 1):

A translation of [AN 4.123](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an04/an04.123.than.html) says:

> The devas of Brahma's retinue, monks, have a life-span of **an eon**. A run-of-the-mill person having stayed there, having used up all the life-span of those devas, goes to hell, to the animal womb, to the state of the hungry shades.
>
> The Abhassara devas, monks, have a life-span of **two eons**. A run-of-the-mill person having stayed there, having used up all the life-span of those devas, goes to hell, to the animal womb, to the state of the hungry shades.
>
> The Subhakinha devas, monks, have a life-span of **four eons**. A run-of-the-mill person having stayed there, having used up all the life-span of those devas, goes to hell, to the animal womb, to the state of the hungry shades.
>
> The Vehapphala devas, monks, have a life-span of **500 eons.** A run-of-the-mill person having stayed there, having used up all the life-span of those devas, goes to hell, to the animal womb, to the state of the hungry shades.
>
> But a disciple of the Blessed One, having stayed there, having used up all the life-span of those devas, is unbound right in that state of being. This, monks, is the difference, this the distinction, this the distinguishing factor, between an educated disciple of the noble ones and an uneducated run-of-the-mill person, when there is a destination, a reappearing.